# Structured data vs unstructured data?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb

Ive been using mongoDB documents just to test out my application. From what ive read, mongoDB is suppose to be unstructured data. However, im confused because my documents have fields like id, title. Isn't this some what structured?

Could someone give me some examples of structured and unstructured data from database?

Comment: Please review the [ask] section and [edit] your question in order to provide a [mcve].

Comment: There's no need to be impolite or vindictive, striking back like that :-(. This is a community and everyone should be doing their bit to improve it.

Comment: ohhhh okay, i apologize :((((((

Answer (score 2):

Unstructured data has internal structure but is not structured via pre-defined data models or schema.

You can have a row containing 4 fields & another row containing 15 fields. Here if you don't have data for some fields or columns you are not storing them or else you are ignoring them. While developing an application at a later stage you might find need to add some fields, this is where unstructured databases play a major role.

Comment: Could you provide some examples please?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a NoSQL database. In simple terms, you are not required to create tables with column names and its data type as in the case of SQL database. The data you store in MongoDB won't be organized internally as a table. However, you are still required to store the data in fashion of key-value pairs (JSON format) in collections.

For example: `db.details.find().pretty();`, where `details` is the name of the Collection:

```
{                                                                          
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b93721978b7d31f00fc1bd7"),                      
        "id" : "15IT112",                                                  
        "name" : "Shivam"                                                                                                                                                
}                                                                          
{                                                                          
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b93722d78b7d31f00fc1bd8"),                      
        "id" : "15IT113",                                                  
        "name" : "Reena"                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

In addition to this, MongoDB does provide an option to structure the database using Mongoose, which is an Object-relational mapper. You can define the schema as you like.

For example:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let detailSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Unstructured data has internal structure but is not structured via pre-defined data models or schema.`

This is usually the definition found online, but understandably, is confusing.

In an example using MongoDB documents, these documents are defined using a schema and model. This is the `internal structure` used to define unstructured data.

However, documents are not structured via pre-defined data models or schema. This means that `documents are stored in a way that is not structured via pre-defined models or schema`. Instead, they are stored in collections, which do not follow a pre-defined model or schema.